# Validate Entered Regex in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, validation

I have a formcontrol to enter regex, with which expressions are stored in database. I have added async validation to validate. But it is always coming as true.

```
function regExValidation(control:AbstractControl):{[key:string]:boolean}|null{
let isValid = true;
 try{
  new RegExp(control.value);
  isValid = true;
 }
 catch{
   isValid = null;
 }

return {'isRegexValid' : isValid };
}
```

Comment: Which inputs have you tried?

Comment: /[a-z]+- @maio290

Comment: Well, this is a valid regular expression. `!(` isn't one, for example.